# Reverse the logic of two "or" statements in JavaScript if query

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

I have an `if` test in JavaScript which achieves what I want but not as elegantly as possible. It goes like this:

```
if (x > y || p < q) {
    // don't do anything
} else {
   doSomeFunction();
}
```

If there any way to flip the logic of this so there's only a single `if` statement without having to have a dummy if-condition as well as the `else` condition?

Comment: What is opposite of `>` and `<`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`!` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29) to invert the condition:

```
if (!(x > y || p < q)) {
   doSomeFunction();
}
```

Or simply rewrite the condition like this:

```
if (x <= y && p >= q) {
   doSomeFunction();
}
```

Note: See [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for an explanation about why these two conditions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply invert the comparisons and the logical OR.

```
if (x <= y && p >= q) {
    doSomeFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with the other answer, the last option (less readable) is :

```
(x > y || p < q) || doSomeFunction();
```

If the left bracket is true, it will **NOT** execute the function.

Comment: Thanks Karl-André, I had no idea you could write JS like that! But I guess, as you said, the other answers are more readable.

Comment: This works, but I believe [Brendan Eich would call it abusage](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/). "*… please don’t abuse `&&` and `||` where the mighty `if` statement serves better.*"

Comment: @p.s.w.g not saying to use it, just giving a *possible* solution, i would use the if in this case.

Comment: Absolutely. That was not a criticism, just a note. :)