# >NET Core Razor multiple Where conditions

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, conditional-statements

I have a List of data I'm bringing into the Razor view and I'd like to filter it at this point.  For some reason, the Where doesn't work when I:

```
@foreach (var t in Model.ToDoLists.Where(t => t.Status != "Complete" || t.Status != "Delete" || 
   t.Status != "delete"))
```

But, I can be silly and do this and it works:

```
@foreach (var t in Model.ToDoLists.Where(t => t.Status != "Complete").Where(b => b.Status != 
"Delete").Where(c => c.Status != "delete"))
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Join the conditions in the first example with AND (&&) not with OR (||)  If the status is "DELETE" is, of course, different from "COMPLETE"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# If not (this) Or (this) or (this) - Multiple condition IF/OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580337/c-sharp-if-not-this-or-this-or-this-multiple-condition-if-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Steve` said,you can use `&&` rather than `||`,and you can use ToLower,so that you don't need to check `Delete`:

```
@foreach (var t in Model.ToDoLists.Where(t => t.Status != "Complete"&& t.Status.ToLower() != "delete"))
```